# Applying Spinner set adapter in fragment cause NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-spinner

I have some problem in set adapter to spinner in fragment , it keep cause NullPointerException
I have no idea what's going on , please help thanks

```
public class GradeFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String[] LIST = { "102-1", "102-2","103-1","103-2" };

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        arrayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
        spinner.setPrompt("select");
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerSelectedListener());
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    class SpinnerSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {    

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parents, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            String str = parents.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    }
}
```

**spinner**:

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="40dip"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Log:

```
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.grade/com.example.grade.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class fragment 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class fragment 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.example.grade.InFragment.onCreateView(InFragment.java:14) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4717) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.example.grade.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     ... 11 more 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.example.grade.GradeFragment.onCreateView(GradeFragment.java:77)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4717) 
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-10 23:21:16.316: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     ... 31 more
```

Comment: How is the spinner defined in your XML file?  Can you show us the XML?

Comment: Your subclassing a ListFragment, and then trying to grab a spinner from it R.id.spinner. I don't think there is a view R.id.spinner.

Comment: @Samus Arin Hi, can you speak more specific? why there isn't a view R.id.spinner?Or how can I solve this situation? thx

Answer (score 3):

Check if the getActivity() is null on the "getActivity().getApplicationContext()" in the onCreateView() it might be called before the Activity is bound to the Fragment, specially when you're defining the Fragment in the XML.

So move the creation of the "Adapter" to the onActivityCreated().

Comment: Moving the declaration to onActivityCreated was the right thing to do for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since your sublcassing a ListFragment, you don't need to inflate your view, so remove the line

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
```

note: if you did want a handler to your list view, you'd simply do

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

however there is no spinner in this view, so it wont help here.

You need to add your spinner to this "FragmentList" view, and one way to do it would be to inflate it

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MY_SPINNER_LAYOUT, container, this);
```